# How to use ISO JS date in custom Postgres query WHERE clause, through Sequelize ORM when Postgres date is stored in TIMESTAMPTZ format?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using the Sequalize ORM, but decided to do a custom query for one of my APIs.

Here is the code:

```
 const datetimestamp = new Date(req.body.datetimestamp);


  const comments = await sequelize.query(
    `SELECT "streamcomments"."id" as "commentId","members"."id" as "memberId", "members"."userName", "streamcomments"."comment", "streamcomments"."status", "streamcomments"."likesNumber", "streamcomments"."praisesNumber", "streamcomments"."likes", "streamcomments"."praises", "streamcomments"."createdAt" FROM "streamcomments" JOIN "streammembers" ON "streammembers"."id" = "streamcomments"."streamMemberId" JOIN "members" ON "members"."id" = "streammembers"."memberId" WHERE "streamcomments."."createdAt" < ${datetimestamp} AND "streamcomments"."streamId" = ${stream.id} ORDER BY "streamcomments"."createdAt" DESC LIMIT 50` 
  );
```

But when it runs with a Javascript ISO date, for some reason the ISO date is converted into an unknown format before it gets to Postgres.  Here is the error I'm receiving:

```
Executing (default): SELECT     "streamcomments"."id" as "commentId","members"."id" as "memberId", "members"."userName", "streamcomments"."comment", "streamcomments"."status", "streamcomments"."likesNumber", "streamcomments"."praisesNumber", "streamcomments"."likes", "streamcomments"."praises", "streamcomments"."createdAt" FROM "streamcomments" JOIN "streammembers" ON "streammembers"."id" = "streamcomments"."streamMemberId" JOIN "members" ON "members"."id" = "streammembers"."memberId" WHERE "streamcomments."."createdAt" < Mon Apr 17 2023 16:15:34 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time) AND "streamcomments"."streamId" = 1 ORDER BY "streamcomments"."createdAt" DESC LIMIT 50
Error
    at Query.run (/home/anonuser/working/JS_Projects/churchsocialAPI/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:50:25)
    at /home/anonuser/working/JS_Projects/churchsocialAPI/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:311:28
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async /home/anonuser/working/JS_Projects/churchsocialAPI/controllers/stream.js:173:20 {
  name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  parent: error: syntax error at or near "Apr"
```

**I have two questions:**

1. What is causing the automatic re-formatting of the Javascript date object to:

   Mon Apr 17 2023 16:15:34 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)
2. How do I pass in the date to Postgres so it can be used successfully in the where clause?

**UPDATE:** I've solved it another way and since moved on: I used the postgres auto-id column for grabbing more posts, since they are sequential and can be trusted for mimicking chronological order 100%.  But I'm still curious how to pass datetimestamps through Sequelize to Postgres in a custom query if anybody is up for a challenge.

Comment: Before attempting to fix the date format problem, fix the SQLI and use parameterised queries with sequelize.

Comment: "*What is causing the automatic re-formatting of the ISO Javascript date?*" - not sure what you think an "ISO JS date" is. You have a JS `Date` instance, which is an object, which has nothing to do with the ISO date string format. So it's not "reformatted" either - embedding it in a template literal uses ordinary `.toString()` with the format you experience. Explicitly call `datetimestamp.toISOString()` instead if you want an ISO date string.

Comment: I tried that as well, but didn't want to clog up the question.  I'll clarify the question though - thanks.

Comment: "*but decided to do a custom query for one of my APIs*" - why? What would it look like with a normal query?

Comment: @Bergi I explicity said in the question I decided to use a custom query; hence not a parameterized query.  I might alter that if using Sequelize parameterized query would solve it, however.

Comment: It would absolutely solve it, yes. Sequelize knows how to serialise dates (and the `streamId`) properly.

Comment: And even with a [custom query](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/sequelize.js~sequelize#instance-method-query), you should be using query parameters and the `replacements`/`bind` options

Comment: Also, *why* did you decide to use a custom query?

Comment: @Bergi because that approach would require me to solve dependency challenges that I don't have time for.  Hope that clarifies why I went in the custom query route.

Comment: "*I'm still curious how to pass datetimestamps through Sequelize to Postgres in a custom query*" - didn't I link the solution already? Use query parameters in the custom query, instead of string interpolation.